# BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress() not updating property and locking up the UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

i am using a `backgroundWorker` to do a long running operation:

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true, WorkerReportsProgress = true };

backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{

};

backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
{
    someViewModel.SomeProperty.Add((SomeObject)args.UserState);
};

backgroundWorker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    someViewModel.SomeList.ForEach(x =>
    {
        someViewModel.SomeInterface.SomeMethod(backgroundWorker, someViewModel, someViewModel.SomeList, x);
    });
};

backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then in `SomeInterface.SomeMethod`:

```
public void SomeMethod(BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker, SomeViewModel someViewModel//....)
{
    //Filtering happens

    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, someObjectFoundWhileFiltering);
}
```

So, when it comes to:

```
backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
{
    someViewModel.SomeProperty.Add((SomeObject)args.UserState);//Adding the found object to the Property in the VM
};
```

On the line `someViewModel.SomeProperty.Add((SomeObject)args.UserState);`, the set on the `SomeProperty` is not firering and the `UI` just locks up.

**What am i doing wrong? Is this the correct way to update the `UI thread`?**

Comment: Put   backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, someObjectFoundWhileFiltering); in DoWork() method. Any reason to have  in called method?

Comment: What is the type of SomeProperty. Are you sure the Add method firering an event (like NotifyPropertyChanged). How catch you the change of SomeProperty in someviewmodel object?

Comment: The code looks basically OK, what is someViewModel.SomeProperty exactly?

Comment: @HenkHolterman `someViewModel.SomeProperty` is a `List<EntityObject>`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have never seen an error like this before. When i comment out `someViewModel.SomeProperty.Add((SomeObject)args.UserState);`, then everything works fine. So i am guessing it has got to do with the `someObjectFoundWhileFiltering`, which is of type `EntityObject`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Is it not maybe because `someObjectFoundWhileFiltering` is created on the worker thread and when i try to add it to the `List` on the UI thread it is breaking because the worker thread owns this object?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I get no `Exception`, it just locks up...

Comment: Possibly you just hit the `updateprogress` extremely often. I've had my GUI lock up before that way... By the way; the 'set' of the property won't fire if you do an `.Add()` on it...

Comment: @Mr47 At the moment it only hits once, so it is not that...

Comment: A simple List.Add shouldn't fail or lock up so maybe an event is fired and then things go wrong.

Comment: OK I am not an MVVM person but why are you passing the whole view model around.  Could you not perform a calculation on specific data in the DoWork and then update the model on the Complete and Progress?  You are doing a SomeList.ForEach but then still passing SomeList.  Heck you are passing the both the someViewModel, someViewModel.SomeList.  Yes by ref this is fast but still why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around for now:

DeepClone the `object`.

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    ViewModel.SomeList = DeepClone<List<SomeObject>>(ViewModel.TempList);
};

backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var item = DeepClone<SomeObject>((SomeObject)args.UserState);

    ViewModel.TempList.Add(item);
};

public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Position = 0;

        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're developing a Windows Form application, then coming to your point if you're updating or sending some values to the form components you need to do so with delegate, to place your request in main thread Q, try in this way might you will find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-thread calls to winforms controls are dangerous. They can lead to unpredictable results.
Sometimes you get the special exception. Sometimes UI is just not redrawn... In your case you are getting hanging.

To avoid this make calls to UI like described in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx .
Like this:

```
private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {   
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Note that this metod must be put into UI context so *this* refers to **From** or **Control**.
Invoke puts requests into UI message queue and then it will be exctracted and processed by UI message loop which runs in UI thread.